# Capture all characters in single string between regex matches

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, parsing, text

I have a log file with the following format:

```
00:00:09.476 ;; 00:00:11.111 side:start top:15% bottom:10% sound:80%
FOO BAR FOO FOO FOO BAR

00:00:11.111 ;; 00:00:12.278 side:start top:15% bottom:10% sound:78%
BAR BAR BAR' BAR. FOO.BAR

00:00:12.278 ;; 00:00:14.447 side:start top:15% bottom:10% sound:43%
BOO.BOO. FARFAR.FAR
```

What I am trying to do is capture all of the text beneath the log data for each entry, so ultimately, end up with a list looking like:

`['FOO BAR FOO FOO FOO BAR', 'BAR BAR BAR' BAR. FOO.BAR', 'BOO.BOO. FARFAR.FAR']`

I have written the following regular expression and [tested that it properly matches the log data](https://regex101.com/r/Nowwbr/1):

```
"\d\d:\d\d:\d\d.\d\d\d ;; \d\d:\d\d:\d\d.\d\d\d side:start top:\d\d% bottom:\d\d% sound:\d\d%"
```

But I am looking to capture all of the information *between* these matches, and I am not certain if this is even the best way to do it, vs iterating through the `123,378` line text file and ignoring both blank spaces and *matches* to the above expression.

What is the most efficient way to return a list of the text after each log entry?

Comment: There is no `-->` in the example data that you have in the pattern

Comment: @Thefourthbird thank you for noticing my error. Was changing some things to keep the example relevant without having it to close to the actual problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use re.findall with a pattern using a lookahead:

```
^\d\d:\d\d:\d\d.\d\d\d ;; \d\d:\d\d:\d\d.\d\d\d .*((?:\n(?!\d\d:\d\d:\d\d.\d\d\d ;; \d\d:\d\d:\d\d.\d\d\d).*)*)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7QSuXx/1)

```
import re

pattern = r"^\d\d:\d\d:\d\d.\d\d\d ;; \d\d:\d\d:\d\d.\d\d\d .*((?:\n(?!\d\d:\d\d:\d\d.\d\d\d ;; \d\d:\d\d:\d\d.\d\d\d).*)*)"

s = ("00:00:09.476 ;; 00:00:11.111 side:start top:15% bottom:10% sound:80%\n"
            "FOO BAR FOO FOO FOO BAR\n\n"
            "00:00:11.111 ;; 00:00:12.278 side:start top:15% bottom:10% sound:78%\n"
            "BAR BAR BAR' BAR. FOO.BAR\n\n"
            "00:00:12.278 ;; 00:00:14.447 side:start top:15% bottom:10% sound:43%\n"
            "BOO.BOO. FARFAR.FAR")

res = [x.strip() for x in re.findall(pattern, s, re.M)]
print(res)
```

Output

```
['FOO BAR FOO FOO FOO BAR', "BAR BAR BAR' BAR. FOO.BAR", 'BOO.BOO. FARFAR.FAR']
```

Or if the data is that specific, shorten it to:

```
^\d\d:\d\d:\d\d.\d{3} ;; .*((?:\n(?!\d\d:\d\d:\d\d.\d{3} ;;).*)*)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HkfB4T/1)

Comment: Ah a [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), this is perfect. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Alternative solution, using [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) (the regex is then simpler):

```py
import re
from itertools import groupby

text = """\
00:00:09.476 ;; 00:00:11.111 side:start top:15% bottom:10% sound:80%
FOO BAR FOO FOO FOO BAR

00:00:11.111 ;; 00:00:12.278 side:start top:15% bottom:10% sound:78%
BAR BAR BAR' BAR. FOO.BAR

00:00:12.278 ;; 00:00:14.447 side:start top:15% bottom:10% sound:43%
BOO.BOO. FARFAR.FAR"""

pat = re.compile(r"\d\d:\d\d:\d\d\.\d\d\d ;;")

out = []
for v, g in groupby(text.splitlines(), lambda l: pat.match(l)):
    if not v:
        out.append("\n".join(g).strip())

print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
['FOO BAR FOO FOO FOO BAR', 
 "BAR BAR BAR' BAR. FOO.BAR", 
 'BOO.BOO. FARFAR.FAR']
```